My content on Code Review was used by some YouTubers to make bad videos, what can I do about it?
I don't know if it is on topic here, but it does involve this website. In fact this is only possible because this website exists, but the Stack Exchange network is not at fault.
So a little information about me, I was born on April 10, 1999 and I am non-binary, liberal, woke, anti-traditionalist and self-determinist, I dropped out off senior high school in the last term, I am unemployed and I live with my mother and she provides economical support for me and she covers my costs of living.
I live with my mother because my father died in 2019 and I am the only-child, there is no one else in my family besides my mother (excluding extended family), and my relationship is bad with my mother. And I don't have friends, never had any.
Oh, and I was born in China and that makes me ethnically Chinese, but to drive my point home, no one chooses where they were born, their skin color or even to be born.
I am always a loner and I never had anything in common with other people, my age or otherwise, my interests and the interests of the masses never overlap, and I never had any common language with anyone I personally know, I always liked expanding the sphere of the known and understanding the natural universe. I am hyper intelligent but I have trouble communicating with all other people.
So today I had an idea to search my username using Google, just to see what I can find, my username is "Ξένη Γήινος" if you somehow missed it, I chose it myself and I won't tell you what it means (though of course you can use Google translate), I chose it because it is unique, I ensured that Google search returned absolutely zero results when I searched "Ξένη Γήινος", and I don't expect Non-Greeks to understand its meaning (so you don't have any preconceptions about me, though its meaning is fitting).
I expected to find nothing other than my user profiles on the Stack Exchange network and my posts, I expected searching my username will turn up webpages on this network because I found this network through Google search, sites in this network pop up in search results quite often.
But I expected nothing else, because I haven't posted anything on any social media yet, I don't have any online footprint and I am practically invisible. But somehow it seems I have already made an impact, whether I like it or not.
To my surprise, I have found several YouTube videos that had used my code in them WITHOUT MY PERSONAL CONSENT OR ACKNOWLEDGEMENT, they didn't even try to contact me or anything (though of course they wouldn't find my contact methods if they tried, for the record my email is estranger921@gmail.com and don't try to reach me via email, I only open GMail for account verification, and I block all phone calls not from my mother, not that she calls often), though they still had the decency to attribute to me in the video description.
These videos are linked below (at least the ones I can find):
Codereview: Python script to split overlapping ranges, version 4
Which uses Python script to split overlapping ranges, version 4 WITHOUT MY CONSENT OR ACKNOWLEDGEMENT
How to identify file by "File Record Segment"?
Which uses How to identify file by "File Record Segment"? WITHOUT MY CONSENT OR ACKNOWLEDGEMENT
Codereview: Middle-outwards alternating iterator
Which uses My answer to Middle-outwards alternating iterator WITHOUT MY CONSENT OR ACKNOWLEDGEMENT
C++ OpenMP doesn't speed up matrix multiplication
Which uses C++ OpenMP doesn't speed up matrix multiplication WITHOUT MY CONSENT OR ACKNOWLEDGEMENT
Codereview: Sieve of Eratosthenes in C++ with wheel factorization
Which uses Sieve of Eratosthenes in C++ with wheel factorization WITHOUT MY CONSENT OR ACKNOWLEDGEMENT
How to define an unordered_map at global level?
Which uses How to define an unordered_map at global level? WITHOUT MY CONSENT OR ACKNOWLEDGEMENT
Codereview: Automate the boring stuff with python - The Collatz Sequence
Which uses My answer to Automate the boring stuff with python - The Collatz Sequence WITHOUT MY CONSENT OR ACKNOWLEDGEMENT
Unexpected uint64 behaviour 0xFFFF'FFFF'FFFF'FFFF - 1 = 0?
Which uses My answer to Unexpected uint64 behaviour 0xFFFF'FFFF'FFFF'FFFF - 1 = 0? WITHOUT MY CONSENT OR ACKNOWLEDGEMENT
Codereview: Python script that makes generalized Ulam spirals
Which uses Python script that makes generalized Ulam spirals WITHOUT MY CONSENT OR ACKNOWLEDGEMENT
Codereview: Python data class that is a mixture of dict and namedtuple
Which uses Python data class that is a mixture of dict and namedtuple WITHOUT MY CONSENT OR ACKNOWLEDGEMENT
Windows 10 falsely reports no internet
Which uses Windows 10 falsely reports no internet WITHOUT MY CONSENT OR ACKNOWLEDGEMENT
A whopping 11 videos in total (That I have managed to find).
I have written a quick Python script to get the statistics about these videos:
import json
import requests

API_KEY = "it's private"

URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={vid}&part=snippet%2Cstatistics&key={api}"

HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:133.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/133.0"
}

video_ids = [
    'DnI6xHGQrkI',
    '4YZgnV5lqL4',
    'pcdNF3D-h0w',
    'SLr_wvBlx8U',
    'j5FQWHwWbak',
    'tKxIhZqYWnE',
    'irUaw3GtD3A',
    'hioGs6t4E2U',
    'ih0fkMQgUc0',
    'FMyKkMiiVFg',
    'K6KjywYlgFk'
]

STATS = {}

for vid in video_ids:
    data = requests.get(URL.format(vid=vid, api=API_KEY), headers=HEADERS).json()["items"][0]
    entry = {}
    for name in ("publishedAt", "channelId", "title", "channelTitle"):
        entry[name] = data["snippet"][name]
    
    for name in ("viewCount", "likeCount"):
        entry[name] = int(data["statistics"][name])
    
    STATS[vid] = entry

print(json.dumps(STATS, indent=4))

total_views = sum(i["viewCount"] for i in STATS.values())
total_likes = sum(i["likeCount"] for i in STATS.values())

print(f"Total views: {total_views}, Average views: {total_views / 11:.03f}; Total likes: {total_likes}, Average likes: {total_likes / 11:.03f}")
counts = {}
for v in STATS.values():
    name = v["channelTitle"]
    counts[name] = counts.setdefault(name, 0) + 1

print(json.dumps(counts, indent=4))

And the results:
{
    "DnI6xHGQrkI": {
        "publishedAt": "2023-11-11T13:24:43Z",
        "channelId": "UCC7CTZYg94VpWuiTuAMNQhw",
        "title": "Codereview: Python script to split overlapping ranges, version 4",
        "channelTitle": "Sophia Wagner",
        "viewCount": 5,
        "likeCount": 0
    },
    "4YZgnV5lqL4": {
        "publishedAt": "2024-06-21T03:05:36Z",
        "channelId": "UCmZh4TFaZDcpwNW9jxty5ig",
        "title": "How to identify file by \"File Record Segment\"?",
        "channelTitle": "Peter Schneider",
        "viewCount": 3,
        "likeCount": 0
    },
    "pcdNF3D-h0w": {
        "publishedAt": "2023-08-05T06:42:28Z",
        "channelId": "UCmZh4TFaZDcpwNW9jxty5ig",
        "title": "Codereview: Middle-outwards alternating iterator",
        "channelTitle": "Peter Schneider",
        "viewCount": 1,
        "likeCount": 0
    },
    "SLr_wvBlx8U": {
        "publishedAt": "2023-09-11T17:01:09Z",
        "channelId": "UCmZh4TFaZDcpwNW9jxty5ig",
        "title": "C++ OpenMP doesn't speed up matrix multiplication",
        "channelTitle": "Peter Schneider",
        "viewCount": 33,
        "likeCount": 1
    },
    "j5FQWHwWbak": {
        "publishedAt": "2023-08-11T02:01:21Z",
        "channelId": "UCmZh4TFaZDcpwNW9jxty5ig",
        "title": "Codereview: Sieve of Eratosthenes in C++ with wheel factorization",
        "channelTitle": "Peter Schneider",
        "viewCount": 40,
        "likeCount": 1
    },
    "tKxIhZqYWnE": {
        "publishedAt": "2023-08-12T07:39:44Z",
        "channelId": "UCmZh4TFaZDcpwNW9jxty5ig",
        "title": "How to define an unordered_map at global level?",
        "channelTitle": "Peter Schneider",
        "viewCount": 12,
        "likeCount": 0
    },
    "irUaw3GtD3A": {
        "publishedAt": "2023-06-16T02:33:24Z",
        "channelId": "UCmZh4TFaZDcpwNW9jxty5ig",
        "title": "Codereview: Automate the boring stuff with python - The Collatz Sequence",
        "channelTitle": "Peter Schneider",
        "viewCount": 103,
        "likeCount": 0
    },
    "hioGs6t4E2U": {
        "publishedAt": "2023-05-09T17:04:15Z",
        "channelId": "UCmZh4TFaZDcpwNW9jxty5ig",
        "title": "Unexpected uint64 behaviour 0xFFFF'FFFF'FFFF'FFFF - 1 = 0?",
        "channelTitle": "Peter Schneider",
        "viewCount": 13,
        "likeCount": 0
    },
    "ih0fkMQgUc0": {
        "publishedAt": "2024-06-22T12:01:43Z",
        "channelId": "UCC7CTZYg94VpWuiTuAMNQhw",
        "title": "Codereview: Python script that makes generalized Ulam spirals",
        "channelTitle": "Sophia Wagner",
        "viewCount": 2,
        "likeCount": 0
    },
    "FMyKkMiiVFg": {
        "publishedAt": "2023-06-08T13:26:33Z",
        "channelId": "UCmZh4TFaZDcpwNW9jxty5ig",
        "title": "Codereview: Python data class that is a mixture of dict and namedtuple",
        "channelTitle": "Peter Schneider",
        "viewCount": 9,
        "likeCount": 1
    },
    "K6KjywYlgFk": {
        "publishedAt": "2024-05-13T08:15:07Z",
        "channelId": "UCC7CTZYg94VpWuiTuAMNQhw",
        "title": "Windows 10 falsely reports no internet",
        "channelTitle": "Sophia Wagner",
        "viewCount": 70,
        "likeCount": 3
    }
}
Total views: 291, Average views: 26.455; Total likes: 6, Average likes: 0.545
{
    "Sophia Wagner": 3,
    "Peter Schneider": 8
}

These videos have average views of 26.455 with the most viewed video having 103 videos which completely skewered the average, and average likes of 0.545, the most liked video has a like count of 6.
They are produced by two YouTubers: Peter Schneider and Sophia Wagner, I don't know these people at all. Notice their channel identifiers both contain QandA.
First let's talk about the descriptions, all the video descriptions follow the same format:
Python script that makes generalized Ulam spirals\n Hey guys! Hopefully you found a solution that helped you!\n The Content is licensed under (https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/licensing) CC BY-SA. \n Attention! This video does always use the same license as the source!\nThanks to all the great people for their contributions!\n\n (codereview.stackexchange.com/users/234107/%ce%9e%ce%ad%ce%bd%ce%b7-%ce%93%ce%ae%ce%b9%ce%bd%ce%bf%cf%82)Ξένη Γήινος \n (codereview.stackexchange.com/users/219610/kelly-bundy)Kelly Bundy \n (codereview.stackexchange.com/users/200133/shapeofmatter)ShapeOfMatter \n A special thanks goes out to the awesome (codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286248/python-script-that-makes-generalized-ulam-spirals)Stackexchange community \n \n If anything is off, please write me at sophia DO.T wagner A.T ois42.de\n I wish you all a chilled day! Stay safe :)\n \n  performance algorithm python-3.x python

From https://youtu.be/ih0fkMQgUc0, Sophia Wagner, notice how the HTML syntax is completely broken:
Python script that makes generalized Ulam spirals
 Hey guys! Hopefully you found a solution that helped you!
 The Content is licensed under (https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/l...) CC BY-SA. 
 Attention! This video does always use the same license as the source!
Thanks to all the great people for their contributions!

 (codereview.stackexchange.com/users/234107/%ce%9e%ce%ad%ce%bd%ce%b7-%ce%93%ce%ae%ce%b9%ce%bd%ce%bf%cf%82)Ξένη Γήινος 
 (codereview.stackexchange.com/users/219610/kelly-bundy)Kelly Bundy 
 (codereview.stackexchange.com/users/200133/shapeofmatter)ShapeOfMatter 
 A special thanks goes out to the awesome (codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286248/python-script-that-makes-generalized-ulam-spirals)Stackexchange community 
 
 If anything is off, please write me at sophia DO.T wagner A.T ois42.de
 I wish you all a chilled day! Stay safe :)
 
  performance algorithm python-3.x python

And the whole thing is a liability waiver that doesn't tell you anything about the video itself, but it's purpose is to use CC-BY-SA license as an umbrella against legal prosecution.
And
Sieve of Eratosthenes in C++ with wheel factorization\nI hope you found a solution that worked for you :)\n The Content (except music & images) is licensed under (https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/licensing)CC BY-SA  \nThanks to all those great people for their contributions!\n\n (codereview.stackexchange.com/users/234107/%ce%9e%ce%ad%ce%bd%ce%b7-%ce%93%ce%ae%ce%b9%ce%bd%ce%bf%cf%82)Ξένη Γήινος \n (codereview.stackexchange.com/users/129343/g-sliepen)G. Sliepen \n (codereview.stackexchange.com/users/40480/vnp)vnp \n A special thanks goes out to the (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286439/sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-c-with-wheel-factorization)Stackexchange community \n \n I wish you all a wonderful day! Stay safe :)\n \n  beginner performance sieve-of-eratosthenes algorithm c++

from https://youtu.be/j5FQWHwWbak, Peter Schneider, again the HTML syntax is completely broken
Sieve of Eratosthenes in C++ with wheel factorization
I hope you found a solution that worked for you :)
 The Content (except music & images) is licensed under (https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/l... BY-SA  
Thanks to all those great people for their contributions!

 (codereview.stackexchange.com/users/234107/%ce%9e%ce%ad%ce%bd%ce%b7-%ce%93%ce%ae%ce%b9%ce%bd%ce%bf%cf%82)Ξένη Γήινος 
 (codereview.stackexchange.com/users/129343/g-sliepen)G. Sliepen 
 (codereview.stackexchange.com/users/40480/vnp)vnp 
 A special thanks goes out to the (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/... community 
 
 I wish you all a wonderful day! Stay safe :)
 
  beginner performance sieve-of-eratosthenes algorithm c++

This whole thing again is a liability waiver, and the link to the license doesn't even work: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/licensing)CC
And then let's talk about the contents of these videos. I'll be blunt, these videos are trash, completely trash.
They all have the same format, they all have awful music that the video is better off without, then they start with a person walking outside and talking to the camera, it is obvious said person holds the phone they are using the record this, and they don't talk about anything relevant to the content of the videos at all.
Then it's the card "The Question", followed by a scrolling plain text that is copy-pasted from question body of the post linked. Then another card like "3 Solutions found", followed by a scrolling text of all the text copy-pasted from the answers of the linked post.
That is it. No voice overs, no attempts to explain what the question is, no attempts to explain what the answers are, how the answers worked... No attempts to teach anything to the viewers. In fact, no attempts to even pretend to comprehend the problem at all.
These YouTubers demonstrate absolutely no knowledge about the subject matters, all the videos are extremely basic and they only demonstrate the YouTubers' absolute technological incompetence.
I spent years learning programming, I did it all I did by myself, through countless trial and error, experimentation and perseverance. I created mathematical art, to convert equations and numbers to artistic images through the power of code, to express the patterns I find in nature, to reflect the things that only I see, to explore the intersection between science and art, to create these:







I tried my best to solve NP-Hard problems, scratching my head for hours on end trying to find the most efficient solution; I tried my best to go low-level with Python, delving head-first into proprietary binary formats; I tried my best to find the best implementation of spiral iterators, that will not be generally useful; I tried my best to implement a linear algebra function that outperforms library ones, using only my limited knowledge in both C++ and higher mathematics (and failed); I tried my best to learn C++ with an efficient program that does something instead of "Hello World!" as my first C++ program; I tried my best to make correct and efficient code, spending minutes to write and hours to perfect; I tried my best to tweak Windows to my liking, spending hours Google searching and navigating the labyrinth that is Windows registry...
Everything I do, I give my 100%, I did all these, not because somebody told me to, not because I expect to gain money from them, not even for some recognition... No, I did all these because I find them genuinely interesting, because I wanted to. Yet nobody else ever understands these, nobody ever cares. I got nothing from doing them, and I didn't expect to gain anything other than my content.
Yet now there are these YouTubers who have done none of the things I have done, they know nothing of the things I know, stealing my code and posting on their own channels, profiting off my hard work without doing anything themselves, they steal the fruits of my labor, they get AD money and I get nothing, without even letting me know!
I feel robbed. I feel angry. I want these videos be deleted and these channels be taken down. For your information if you are a programmer and you want to use my code in your project, go ahead and do it, I give you my permission, provided that you understand it, I am glad it can help. But this, this isn't how I wanted my content to be used, this isn't helping anyone and this has no value whatsoever.
What actions can I take in this situation? I can't afford a lawyer and I don't have the time for legal battles, and last but not least I am not in the United States so I can't take this to court even if I wanted to. Are the behaviors of the YouTubers explicitly allowed by CC-BY-SA license? Is there nothing I can do?

Related: YouTube Channels Stealing SE Network Content

There is a lot of irrelevant information in this question, in my opinion: your personal/living situation, gender identity, political stance, images of your mathematical art, etc . That also makes the question unnecessarily long. I suggest that you remove that stuff.

Unfortunately this is a known issue. Some of my content is being scraped by similar actors. There's very little we can do for you.
You can try contacting the Team about this. Those are paid employees from Stack Exchange who may or may not be able to help you with this. They are at least better suited for it than the volunteer moderators who try to keep this site clean.
On the bottom of the page, there's a Contact button. Mark Trust and Safety and state Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution.

Will that solve anything? I doubt it. But that's what you can do. Unless you want to lawyer up, this is basically it.
